# Prawn draw 2 table side by side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I have a table made up of many cells, and in one cell i want to draw a two table side by side,

and i'm using prawn ruby gem

Ex

```
cell_1 = make_cell(:content => "this row content comes directly ", height: 62.5.mm, size: 6)
cell_2 = make_cell(:content => "this row content comes directly ", height: 62.5.mm, size: 6)
cell_3 = make_cell(:content => "this row content comes directly ", height: 62.5.mm, size: 6)
t = make_table([[cell_1],[cell2], [cell3])
t.draw
```

i tried like using

```
t1 = make_table([[cell_1],[cell2], [cell3])
t1.draw
```

But it comes below the first table, how do i make it side by side

Answer (score 0):

it happen because prawn use the "cursor" position, meaning it, everything you write (without bounding boxes) if will just go down.

You can achive that using Bounding boxes, where you can give the position where u want it to start and to end. You can have your both table side by side, just by giving the same y coord.

Let me know if u need a code snippet ;)